# Retina Display Support with SDL

Tags: c, sdl, retina-display

I can't find a single useful thing from any Google search about SDL (2.0) supporting retina displays. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

I'm using this code:

```
//Start SDL
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_Window *screen = NULL;
    SDL_Renderer *render = NULL;
    SDL_Texture *texture = NULL;
    SDL_Event e;
    bool quit = false;
    screen = SDL_CreateWindow("Sample Image",100,100,500,500,SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    render = SDL_CreateRenderer(screen,-1,SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    texture = IMG_LoadTexture(render,"image.bmp");
    if (texture == NULL)
    {
        printf("%s",IMG_GetError());
    }
    //Render all graphics
    SDL_RenderClear(render);
    SDL_RenderCopy(render,texture,NULL,NULL);
    SDL_RenderPresent(render);
    while (quit == false) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e)) {
            if (e.type == SDL_QUIT)
                quit = true;
        }
    }
    //Remove all graphics from memory
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(render);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(screen);
    //Quit SDL
    SDL_Quit();
```

Comment: Does it need to support them? AFAIK you just start SDL with a large display mode (2560×1600 for 13' macbook pro), and draw to the screen as normal. There is no special support needed. It's just a high quality screen.

Comment: Hmm, seems no such support exists.

Comment: What do you mean by no such support? There is no difference between a Retina and normal display, it's just bigger and better quality, SDL is exactly the same.

Comment: Maybe he's talking about control over the scaling?

Comment: Pixel doubling. Things look very pixelated in SDL. Apparently a pixel is equivalent to a point (2x2 pixels) in SDL2. So how would I go about using actual pixels?

Comment: Could you provide a source for that claim?  I've never seen anything to suggest that a pixel in SDL is anything other than a pixel.

Comment: @Haz Myself. I'm using SDL2 on my retina Macbook Pro and everything is pixelated in a window.

Comment: Could you show us the code you're using?

Comment: Done, I added it to the OP. It's not the whole file but you get the gist.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SDL 2.0 retina mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544881/sdl-2-0-retina-mac)

Answer (score 2):

```
SDL_Window* win = SDL_CreateWindow("test",
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 600, 480,
    SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE|SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL|SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI);
```

the "SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI" flag can do it for you.